# is there a simple css property to set line-height with no buffer?

Tags: css

Is there a simple css property to set line-height with no buffer? The css line-height css property can be used to control the space above and below the text on a line.  However, eliminating the buffer seems to be a matter of trial and error and tweaking with the line-height property.  Does css support a simple property to remove this space without the trial and error?  Something like
a line-height-buffer:none property?

Comment: What do you mean with "buffer"?

Comment: What's the buffer? Do you mean padding or maybe outline?

Comment: did you mean space ? just line-height 1 ? https://jsfiddle.net/f48guvnr/

Comment: I think DaniP's comment may be the most appropriate answer.  will you please add it as an answer and then I'll mark it as answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set line-height to the size of the font (for example 16px), the only space above and below the line can be caused by padding and/or margin. So if you use settings like these

```
p { 
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 14px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

, there will be no space between the lines.

But keep in mind that only certain letters reach the full height of the line - a "g" stretches below the *baseline* (not to be confused with *line*), but not up, an "f" might reach the top (and not the bottom) - that always depends on the used font.

P.S.: Instead of using the font-size value, you can also write

```
line-height: 100%;
```

Comment: The font size corresponds to the em square, a concept used in typography. Note that certain glyphs may bleed outside their em squares.

Comment: I tried 2 different approaches but a few pixels still display over and beneath the text on the page:  https://jsbin.com/bewemi/edit?html,css.  Am I missing something here?

Comment: The word "Content" you used in there doesn't contain any letters that go below the baseline. Try to add a "g", for example. And add a background color, then you see it better. I altered your example for demonstration: https://jsbin.com/vuwuyowowa/1/edit?html,css,output  You see the "Ü" character - that even goes above the line height... And there are lots of other special characters that also belong to a font.